# Copy data from string (python)

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, facebook-graph-api

I have some data from facebook Graph API

like:

```
{
  u'paging': {
    u'next': u'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/508246595873195/posts?limit=2&access_token=CAACZAPdJZAhkI8uOZBUJ5yhBFzI1IW3M55wbQT7gO7qcRwZDZD'
  ...data...data...data...
}
```

and more.

I want to copy `https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/508246595873195/posts?limit=2&access_token=CAACZAPdJZAhkI8uOZBUJ5yhBFzI1IW3M55wbQT7gO7qcRwZDZD` only for further requests in python.

Please help!!

Comment: `d['paging']['next']`

Comment: Please explain @AvinashRaj !!!

Comment: Is your data Json? Look at json.dumps https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

Comment: Yes Data is in JSON format. From Graph API (Facebook)

Answer (score 3):

Since your data is in the format of nested dictionaries, you need to navigate through that in-order to get the desired value.

```
>>> d = {u'paging': {u'next': u'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/508246595873195/posts?limit=2&access_token=CAACZAPdJZAhkI8uOZBUJ5yhBFzI1IW3M55wbQT7gO7qcRwZDZD'}}
>>> d['paging']['next']
u'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/508246595873195/posts?limit=2&access_token=CAACZAPdJZAhkI8uOZBUJ5yhBFzI1IW3M55wbQT7gO7qcRwZDZD'
```

You should access a specific dictionary value only through it's key. So `d['paging']` gives the value of the key `paging` which is also a dictionary. Then again specify the key which holds your expected value.